# dynamic memory allocation problem with 0 as output

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to create dynamic memory allocation using `malloc` but always I got 0 as output instead of 5.
My code

```
typedef struct{
    int nl;
    double *vect;
}vect_t;
void creerVecteur(vect_t *ptrVect){
    double *p;
    ptrVect->vect=(double *)malloc(ptrVect->nl*sizeof(double));
    ptrVect->vect[0] = 5;
    ptrVect->vect[1] = 7;
    ptrVect->vect[2] = 2;
    printf("%d\n",ptrVect->vect[0]);
}
int main(){
    vect_t v1;
    v1.nl = 3;
    creerVecteur(&v1);
}
```

Comment: Typo: `printf("%d\n",ptrVect->vect[0]);` should use `%f`.

Comment: You should turn up your compiler warnings. It should show a message about parameter type mismatch for `%d` format specifier. For GCC you can use options `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: Thank you. I did not pay attention to this mistake

Comment: With proper compiler options your compiler will pay attention and tell you.

Comment: We already have thousands of questions with wrong format specifier. These should be closed as simple typo/duplicate, not answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier to `printf`.

The `%d` format specifier is for printing an `int` in decimal format.  To print a `double`, use `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

just use `%g` or `%f` to specify a `double` floating point type to `printf()`.  You are telling `printf()` you ara passing an `int` with `%d`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int nl;
    double *vect;
} vect_t;

void creerVecteur(vect_t *ptrVect)
{
    double *p;
    ptrVect->vect=(double *)malloc(ptrVect->nl * sizeof(double));
    ptrVect->vect[0] = 5;
    ptrVect->vect[1] = 7;
    ptrVect->vect[2] = 2;
    printf("%g\n",ptrVect->vect[0]);
}

int main()
{
    vect_t v1;
    v1.nl = 3;
    creerVecteur(&v1);
}
```

with output:

```
$ a.out
5
$ _
```